# How to set element of numpy array to be numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, oop, neural-network

I want to set a specific element of `self.weights`, which is a `numpy` array, to be another `numpy` array,but i get these two errors:

> "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

> "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.".

Example:

```
self.weights=np.empty(some size)
self.weights[i]=np.random.randn(some size)
```

Here's my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import sys
    
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, inputs, hiddensSizes, outputs, lr, epochs):
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.inputsSize = self.inputs.shape[1]
        self.outputs = outputs
        self.outputsSize = self.outputs.shape[1]
        self.lr = lr
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.hiddensSizes = hiddensSizes
        self.weights = np.empty(len(self.hiddensSizes) + 1)
        self.combinedLayers = np.hstack((self.inputsSize, self.hiddensSizes, self.outputsSize))
        for i in range(len((self.weights))):
            self.weights[i] = np.random.randn(self.combinedLayers[i], self.combinedLayers[i + 1]) #ERROR IS HERE
    
    
NN = NeuralNetwork(np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), (3, 4), np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]), 0.1, 10000)
print(NN.weights)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the shape of `np.random.randn(self.combinedLayers[i], self.combinedLayers[i + 1])` is changing, it is better to use `list`:

```
# code code code
    self.weights = []
# code code code
    for ....:
        self.weights.append(np.random.randn(self.combinedLayers[i], self.combinedLayers[i + 1]))
# code code code
```

But if you want to use `NumPy`, then use `object` datatype as:

```
# code code code
    self.weights =  np.empty(len(self.hiddensSizes) + 1, dtype = 'object')
# code code code
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code returnx the same error.

```
import numpy as np

weights = np.empty(3)
weights[0] = [1, 2]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

But this works :

```
weights[0] = 1
```

---

Each element of the array should have the same number of dimensions (unlike a standard python list). And the default is 1, which is what is used in your case.
And to specify the depth, just pass in a tuple.
Look at the following:

```
weights = np.empty((3, 5))
weights[0] = [1, 2]
```

Will return an error also :

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 5
```

But the following will work, because my assigned list has the expected dimension :

```
weights[0] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Hope you figure it out from there.

Comment: Thank you. Though I have fixed it by setting dtype='object'